# can we customize tableView commitEditingStyle delete button animation?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

When a user swipes to delete the row... The entire row `cell.view` shifts to the left to make room for "Delete" red button.

Can we make it so this shift doesn't occur and the "Delete" red button just slides on top of the `cell.view`?

### As is when "Delete" button is shown, we cannot see important information to know which entry we are about to delete.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a slight alternative, rather than messing with the button, just layout your UITableViewCell differently if its editing. In your UITableViewCell subclass:

OBJC:

```
-(void) layoutSubViews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    if (self.isEditing) {
        self.textLabel.frame = CGRectOffset(self.textLabel.frame, 200,0);
        // or
        self.confirmLabel.text = @"Hey your deleting me!";
        self.confirmLabel.hidden = NO;
    } else {
        self.confirmLabel.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

Swift:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews();
    if (self.editing) {
        self.textLabel!.frame = CGRectOffset(self.textLabel!.frame, 200, 0);
        // or
        self.confirmLabel!.text = "Hey your deleting me!"
        self.confirmLabel!.hidden = false
    } else {
        self.confirmLabel!.hidden = true
    }
}
```